# Cascade insert on one-to-many with fluent NHibernate

Tags: nhibernate, fluent-nhibernate

I have two classes mapped using fluent NHibernate - User and a UserRoleAssignment. An User has many UserRoleAssignments. Here's the relevant map for user:

```
HasMany(x => x.Roles)
.Table("UserRoleMap")
.Cascade.SaveUpdate();
```

And for UserRoleAssignment:

```
Map(x => x.User_Id);
```

As you can see, I'm only referencing from User to UserRoleAssignment. From UserRoleAssignment, I'm only mapping the foreign key column (User_Id).
The problem is, that when I save the user, I get an exception caused by the foreign key constraint, because NHibernate is inserting 0 in the value for the User_id property. This only happens on new users - existing users (which already has an ID), works fine.

So the question is, how can I make sure that NHibernate sets the value of User_Id to the ID generated when inserting the new User?

Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is documented in http://nhibernate.info/doc/nh/en/index.html#collections-onetomany:

> *Very Important Note:* If the `<key>` column of a `<one-to-many>` association is declared `NOT NULL`, NHibernate may cause constraint violations when it creates or updates the association. To prevent this problem, *you must use a bidirectional association* with the many valued end (the set or bag) marked as `inverse="true"`. See the discussion of bidirectional associations later in this chapter.