# Fluent NHibernate One-To-Many Mapping

Tags: nhibernate, fluent-nhibernate, nhibernate-mapping, fluent-nhibernate-mapping

I have the following 2 classes:

**Advert**

```
public virtual int Id { get; set;
public virtual IList<AdvertImage> AdvertImages { get; set; }
```

**AdvertImage**

```
public virtual int Id { get; set; }
public virtual string Filename { get; set;
public virtual Advert Advert { get; set; }
```

In the DB, my AdvertImages table has the FK 'AdvertId' which relates to the Adverts table which has the PK of 'Id'.

This is a One-To-Many mapping, in that one advert can have many images.

My Fluent NHibernate mappings (edited for brevity) are:

**AdvertMap**

```
Id(x => x.Id)
  .GeneratedBy.Identity();
...
HasMany(x => x.AdvertImages)
  .KeyColumn("AdvertId")
  .Inverse();
...
Table("Adverts");
```

**AdvertImageMap**

```
Id(x => x.Id)
  .GeneratedBy.Identity();
...
References(x => x.Advert)
  .Column("AdvertId");
...
Table("AdvertImages");
```

I am creating a new instance of `Advert` in code, then populating the `AdvertImages` property (of Advert) with a `List<AdvertImage>`.

When I go to persist my `Advert` object to the DB, I would like the AdvertImages to be inserted into their AdvertImages table, but due to the relationship between the 2 tables, I need the Advert insertion to happen first, so as the PK Id is generated, which can then be inserted in the AdvertImages table. (When I create my list of AdvertImage, I am populating the Filename property, but obviously don't have the new AdvertId at that stage, so want that to be populated when the advert is persisted to the DB).

I have tried experimenting with different Inverse() and Cascade settings but haven't succeeded yet. Can anyone help please?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

You need to change your `Advert` mapping to cascade:

```
Id(x => x.Id)
  .GeneratedBy.Identity();

HasMany(x => x.AdvertImages)
  .KeyColumn("AdvertId")
  .Inverse()
  .Cascade.AllDeleteOrphan();

Table("Adverts");
```

You should then be able to do something like this to persist an `Advert` object and it's children `AdvertImage`.

```
Advert newAdvert = new Advert();
AdvertImage newImage = new AdvertImage();
newImage.Advert = newAdvert;
newAdvert.AdvertImages.Add(newImage);

using(NHibernate.ISession session = SessionFactory.GetCurrentSession())
{
    using (NHibernate.ITransaction tran = session.BeginTransaction())
    {
        session.Save(newAdvert);
        tran.Commit();
    }
}
```

My entities usually contain Add and Remove methods for bidirectional one to many relationships like this:

```
public class Advert
{
    public virtual IList<AdvertImage> AdvertImages { get; set; }

    public virtual void AddImage(AdvertImage newImage)
    {
        newImage.Advert = this;
        AdvertImages.Add(newImage);
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks Cole W, and nice tip re the Add and Remove methods.

Answer (score 2):

I had the same issue. I spent a while trying all different types of mapping. I then discovered my mappings were fine and it was actually that I needed to wrap my session in a transaction and use the Commit() method after the session.SaveOrUpdate() method.

```
using(var session = sessionFactory.OpenSession()) 
using(var tx = session.BeginTransaction()) 
{ 
// execute code that uses the session 
tx.Commit(); 
}
```

Comment: thanks ..saved a lot of time digging around this issue

Answer (score 1):

What works for me usually is to set the foreign key column to allow nulls in DB - that would be your AdvertId column, but I'm not sure if that would work in your case, since you are using identity. What NHibernate does is INSERT all with one query and then updates child table foreign key column to the correct id of the parent table. Maybe it would work in your case also.

Here's some similar question that might help: [Cascade insert on one-to-many with fluent NHibernate](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3763824/cascade-insert-on-one-to-many-with-fluent-nhibernate)

Comment: That link you included makes no sense as it has nothing to do with `Fluent NHibernate`.

Comment: @KomengeMwandila Although the answer to the question I linked doesn't use Fluent NHibernate, the question does. Besides, Fluent NHibernate doesn't add anything new here. It just provides another interface to NHibernate mapping. Once you understand how mapping works, you can apply it to Fluent NHibernate, XML mapping, mapping by code...