# NHibernate mapping returns null value

Tags: nhibernate, fluent-nhibernate, nhibernate-mapping

I have a problem with mapping in NHibernate.

The `Order` table has the `Invoice_Id` column which is the nullable `FK` to the `Invoice` table.

The problem is, when I load an `Invoice` which `Id` exists in the `Order` table, I see that `ConnectedOrder` property is null, why?

```
public class Invoice
{
    public virtual Order ConnectedOrder { get; set; }
}

public class Order
{
    public virtual Invoice ConnectedInvoice { get; set; }
}


public class InvoiceMap : ClassMap<Invoice>
{
    public InvoiceMap()
    {
        this.References(x => x.ConnectedOrder).Nullable();
    }
}

public class OrderMap : ClassMap<Order>
{
    public OrderMap()
    {
        this.References(x => x.ConnectedInvoice).Nullable();
    }
}
```

### edit

I've changed my classes and mappings like Radim Köhler said, then I found that topic
[Fluent NHibernate One-To-Many Mapping](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10853841/fluent-nhibernate-one-to-many-mapping)

and there was the need to also add:

```
this.HasMany(x => x.Orders)
    .KeyColumn("Invoice_id")
    .Inverse()
    .Cascade
    .AllDeleteOrphan();
```

and now it works

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You may not like it, but the table structure described above, is not representing Entity relations you've created *(so called `one-to-one`)*.

In case, that one table contains column referencing the another table (FK), we have scenario:

- Each Order has exactly one (or null) Invoice. *(`many-to-one`)*
- Invoice can be referenced by none or one or many Orders. *(`one-to-many`)*

That means, that we should express Entities like this:

```
public class Invoice
{   // many orders could reference us
    public virtual IList<Order> Orders { get; set; }
    ...

public class Order
{   // unchanged
    public virtual Invoice ConnectedInvoice { get; set; }
    ...
```

And the mapping should be:

```
public InvoiceMap()
{    // HasMany is one-to-many
     this.HasMany(x => x.Orders)
        ...
}
public OrderMap()
{   // References is many-to-one
    this.References(x => x.ConnectedInvoice).Nullable();
    ...
```

Comment: thanks for the explanation. I changed the classes but still the found Invoice has the Orders count = 0. I also tried to load all Invoices whose have the Orders count > 0, but none Invoices with that criteria were found

Comment: Well if you have the mapping as I described, and even more, you explicitly used for `HasMany` the setting `.KeyColumn("Invoice_Id")` and for `References` you have `.Column('Invoice_Id')` ... then if you are inside of one session - and data are there... all will be loaded. (be sure session is not closed). Could you check that all? Mapping above is ok.